# Slow ssh response on server

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd

On my Centos7 system, whenever I try ssh, the "Login" prompt comes up fast, but the next prompt to ask for password takes about 2 mins to appear. I debugged the ssh session and I found between the below two debugs it gets hung somewhere. After sending 50 packets, it stays put for 2 mins and then it receives 51 packets and then the rest of the part is at normal pace. I have another system which I debugged for ssh but there was no latency observed between those two packet transactions

```
**debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51**
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
```

Comment: Try to add more debug on server side. What kind of path are between the two servers? It seems to be a problem purely related to authentication like PAM or somethng like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there might be several DNS lookup attempts failing during the 2 min delay. The most common reason could be inability to reverse lookup the name of the client host when only its IP address is known.

If you login to the server and run `dig +short -x <client IP address>`, does the prompt come back effectively immediately (with or without an answer), or is there a delay?

If you are not using the GSSAPI authentication methods, disabling them server-side might help. Also ensure that the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `UseDNS no` unless you specifically need the `sshd` to perform DNS lookups.

Comment: A DNS timeout (even if indeed one of the first point to check) would appear even before the traffic displayed that shows the SSH connection has started already.

Comment: I had debugged it with -vvv. Could you tell me how I can further debug it?

Also how did you infer it as a DNS issue? Are there any pages I can refer?